# attaching 32 bit Ubuntu with a 64 bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with other software like ROS and Gazebo on a system with 32 bit Dual Core Processor. But because of some problem, I have to take my hard disk and have to attach it with a system with Intel Xeon E5504 Processor (64-bit processor). Is it OK for me in future? Will it support that?

Kindly reply soon!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well it would work but you won't get the best performance out of Ubuntu. I mean, if you use a 64bit Ubuntu on your 64bit machine it would perform better.

You wouldn't notice the difference when you're doing lite operations with your computer (such as internet browsing or media playing or so) but it would be clear when doing heavy load work (such as 3D modelling or playing some recently released game that requires powerful resources). You should notice that the 64bit performs better.